# Free tool to sync data from ms access to sqlite

Tags: sqlite, ms-access-2003, database-administration, data-synchronization

is there any tool that can compare data from ms-access database table with sqlite table and update it if finds it updated and insert if not found?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't any good tool that allows one click conversion from one db to antoher, so created a utility in c# for the same.